# Do something with the particular element even though click event is fired on class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where a dropdown launcher menu should appear on every row in a list page. I have tweaked the code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGWRdL).

I want the popover (open) behavior be restricted for the click on the particular launcher-icon, though close action is perfect here.

the problem is when any icon is clicked, it shows all menus. My page has rows inflated from a database and every row has three such launcher icons.

I guess this block of code needs some tweaks:

```
// Click event handler to toggle dropdown
$(".button").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // How can I call toggle for the specific div element?
    $(".app-launcher").toggle();
});
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse the DOM to find the `.app-launcher` instance which is related to the clicked `.button` element, to do that use `closest()` and `find()`, like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.launcher').find(".app-launcher").toggle();
});
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPmwwV)

I would also suggest looking in to using a single instance of `.app-launcher` and moving it around the DOM as required to DRY up your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory. :-) Could you please suggest how I can go about using a single instance of .app-launcher? Please point out if this is already explained in SO.